# Can't compile in Visual Studio: can't find WindowsSDKDir variable in registry, or winapifamily.h

Tags: visual-studio-2013

On compiling a program in Visual Studio on a laptop, I'm seeing these warnings/errors:

> warning MSB8003:  Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
>
> error C1083:  Cannot open include file 'winapifamily.':  No such file or directory

On leaving the program (don't know if this is related), I see this error:

> An error occurred while creating or opening the C++ browsing database file c:....sdf.
>
> Ensure that Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 is installed and no other applications are accessing the file.

What should I reinstall, or set?

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was deleted, however I believe it to be correct, so let me clarify it.

If you're targeting Windows XP with Visual Studio 2013 and you get winapifamily.h not found, you're probably missing the Windows 7 Platform SDK. The v120_xp toolset cannot find the V7.1A includes so it includes Windows 8 SDK files which include winapifamily.h (an include that was added in Windows 8) but that doesn't exist with the v120_xp toolset. So like I said, installing the Platform SDK (Windows 7) fixes it.